# Hosting .NET Core Razor Application on Ubuntu 20.04 with NGINX

Tags: nginx, hosting, ubuntu-20.04, asp.net-mvc

I have started trying to self host some projects to get a better understanding of the Networking/Hosting principles and I have been having an issue with hosting a .NET CORE app in Visual Studio following the Razor MVVM pattern.

**Main question is, is this even possible or does it need to be on Windows Server?**

I initially wanted to create two websites off the same domain ie game.domain.com and api.domain.com.

I have one .net core API working so if I go to api.domain.com/swagger/index.html I can see my controllers and all that works fine. However, I thought since I wrote the Razor facing app with .net core as well, I could also host that on the same Ubuntu server with NGINX.

So right now I have two nginx sites setup in folders

- /var/www/api.domain.com/html
- /var/www/twerkle.domain.com/html

Inside each of the html folders, I have a basic index file that gets served as a dummy landing page just to prove I can get to either site through the public IP and it routes it via NGINX. However, I can not seem to get the twerkle.domain.com page to show the main razor .cshtml page.

I followed this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to get the Services setup so it runs the dotnet on the folder's and have the two services running and listing.

[Ubuntu Services running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZO18.png)

Every tutorial or documentation that I have seen has mainly been in regards to .net core apps utilizing them as an *api*.

Here shows the basic index.html landing page being displayed.
[TwerklePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVOaQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I revisted the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and I noticed I had two entries for the game.domain.com address. I modified it so there was just one. I also added the additional /**wwwroot** directory as well as **index index.cshtml** lines. And I noticed my publish folder on the server just had the main .DLLs and an emtpty wwwroot folder, so I moved the .cshtml files over as well. Now I can go to twerkle.domain.com and be served the application I was expecting.

```
    server {
      listen        80;
      server_name  twerkle.domain.com;
      root /var/www/twerkle.domain.com/html/wwwroot; <-- /wwwoot was added
      index index.cshtml; <-- this line was added
      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.cshtml = 404;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      }
    }
```